# Dynamic deeplinking in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink

I was going through the document http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html to learn about deeplinking in Android. I have an activity in my Android app called `WalletActivity` and I have managed to successfully create deeplink for that by making necessary changes in the `AndroidManifest` file.

But, my `WalletActivity` contains a list of options, tapping on which it lands me to another activity `WalletRechargeActivity`, the contents of which depends on the respective option that is selected from the list of options in `WalletActivity`. Now, I want a deeplink that can land me directly on the respective `WalletRechargeActivity` screen itself. How do I do that?

For example, if `example://wallet` lands me to `WalletActivity`, I would like something like `example://wallet/abcd50` to land me to the respective `WalletRechargeActivity` screen with the $50 recharge option. And this value `abcd50` can vary from anything to anything, and is not fixed from beforehand, so I cannot add it in the `AndroidManifest` file with respect to the `WalletRechargeActivity` either, right? I need to handle it dynamically. So, can you tell me how do I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch allows for declarative, annotation-based API to declare application deep links, check it out.

Comment: Simply register a prefix pattern (wallet/*) instead and parse the prefix in your WalletRechargeActivity.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample code to route the user to WalletActivity or WalletRechargeActivity. You can then use the `getIntent().getData()` method to parse the url content.

```
<activity android:name=".WalletActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="example" />

        <data android:host="wallet" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".WalletRechargeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="example" />

        <data android:host="wallet" />

        <data android:pathPattern="/..*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```